# Want to show a hidden button using onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

How do I make a hidden Button called "Add to Cart" appear using onclick?
I have the rest of my code to call function packageTotal(), but need an add to cart button appear also.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
onclick="javascript:packageTotal();addtoCart();">
```

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically set the class of your button

For example, if you have a button like so:

```
<button id="add-to-cart" class="hidden">Add to Card</button>
```

and in your css file:

```
`.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}`
```

and when you want it to appear, just remove the class!

```
$('#add-to-cart').removeClass('hidden')
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in JS/jQuery then I would have the element created in the html and have the CSS display: none; on that element. Whenever it is you activate that element and want it shown then I would simply grab it and use .show() (A jQuery function).

```
$('#addToCart').onClick(function() {
    addItemToCart(item);
    $('#shoppingCartButton').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think question in not clear.. If you are asking how to show <kbd>Add to Cart</kbd> button which is hidden while another event is triggered then.. you can use: `$('#addToCart').show();` where `#addToCart` is id for the button.